# How to move a div from left to right using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `div` named `movingImage` that I want to move to the right 50px every time I click a button.

Here's my javascript:

```
function moving_Image() {
    document.getElementById("movingImage").style.right = "50px";
}
```

And html:

```
<h1 id="movingImage"> __________ </h1>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="moving_Image()">
```

Comment: Why do you guys downvote? He does not know how to do it, but he tryed..

Comment: you're just setting an absolute 50px. you need to increment the right value, e.g. `...style.right += '50px';`

Comment: If you are moving it to the right, either you decrease `.right` value by 50 or increase the `.left` value by 50.

Comment: @CodeiSir He should post the css code that associated with this `div`. Otherwise there is no absolute solution for his issue.

Comment: @Tresdin why do you assume that he has css code associated with the div?

Comment: Won't `+= '50px'` just concatenate strings together?

Comment: @CodeiSir Then how can he know that his `0px width div` moves to the right?

Comment: @Tresdin div? what div? His div is called h1 and it has content

Answer (score 9):

The element you want to move, needs to have the CSS property `position: relative;`:

I also changed `.style.left` to `.style.right`, you will see why:

```js
var imageOffset = 0
function moving_Image() {
  imageOffset += 50
  document.getElementById("movingImage").style.left = imageOffset + "px";
}
```

```css
#movingImage {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="movingImage">__________</h1>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="moving_Image()">
```

If you don't understand something else, please feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Your image moves only once, not every time you click button.

Comment: @EganWolf ah OK, I'll add that real quick

Answer (score 3):

use this code instead:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function movingImage(){
            var movingImage = document.getElementById("movingImage").style.left;
            movingImage.style.left = movingImage.substring(0,MovingImage.length-1) + 50.toString() + "px";
        }
    </script>
    <h1 id="movingImage" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">Move Image!</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Move, Move Image!" onclick="movingImage()"> 
</body>
```

Comment: you don't need to write `.toString()`, it's called implicitly by JavaScript

Comment: an you don't need all that `(parseInt(a.substring(0,a.length-1)) + 50)` - only `... = parseInt(a) + "px"`

Comment: Yes. :D that was a quick answer. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think CodeiSir has it covered, but I wanted to share a few notes that I made playing around with the code about some general JavaScripty things, as well as a couple of new things I learned today.

1) Separate your JS from your HTML.

This

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="moving_Image()">
```

would become

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

and

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = moving_Image;
```

2) There's an element called `offsetLeft` (also `offsetRight`, obvs) which is a read-only attribute that shows by how much the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left. So we can, for example, write:

```
div.style.left = (div.offsetLeft + amount) + 'px';
```

3) It might be fun to have a range of buttons that move the element different amounts, perhaps by adding data attributes to the buttons:

```
<button data-amount="50">by 50</button>
```

We can then process that amount using the `dataset` attribute in the function.

```
function movingImage(e) {
  var amount = +e.target.dataset.amount;
  div.style.left = (div.offsetLeft + amount) + 'px';
}
```

The code in full. Note I'm also passing in the div element with the `click` event.

HTML

```
<div id="movingImage"> __________ </div>
<button data-amount="5">by 5</button>
<button data-amount="20">by 20</button>
<button data-amount="50">by 50</button>
```

JS

```
function movingImage(el, e) {

  // adding a preceding + coerces the string to an integer
  var amount = +e.target.dataset.amount;
  el.style.left = (el.offsetLeft + amount) + 'px';
}

var div = document.getElementById("movingImage");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// [].slice.call basically makes the nodelist an array
// so that you can use the native array functions on it.
[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function (button) {

  // here were just binding the div element to the click
  // event. We could just have easily written
  // button.onclick = movingImage;
  // and then referred to div instead of el in the function
  button.onclick = movingImage.bind(this, div);
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/93jwm24t/)

Answer (score 0):

This is My Version to move a div left to right using javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
           #myDIV {
              position: absolute;
              background-color: coral;
              color: white;
           }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p>
            Click the "Try it" button to position the DIV element 100 pixels from the right edge:
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Note:</strong> If the position property is set to "static", the right property has no effect.
        </p>
    
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    
        <div id="movingImage">
            This is My Div!!
        </div>
    
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
               let movingImage = document.getElementById("movingImage");
               if (movingImage.style.right = "100px") {
                  movingImage.style.right = "0px";
               } else {
                  movingImage.style.right = "100px";
               }
             }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

src: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_left
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp